# Is it possiblchange touchwiz to HTC sense?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, htc-sense, samsung-touchwiz

I have an s6 edge, and i want to change touchwiz skin to HTC sense. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: They have launchers for the play store. If you want it to be your official launcher, then you will have to install a custom rom.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the full Sense experience (both TW and Sense are heavily embedded in SystemUI/framework/etc.), but you can install a bunch of ported Sense apps, including Sense Home, weather, music and many you've come to know about, to get a half-complete one.

Get the set of apps here:

[HTC Sense™ Home - Themes | New Apps | Sense 7 | for all devices [19/10/2015]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/htc-blinkfeed-plugins-devices-08-03-2015-t3049438)